# Using cookies for local sites issue

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm using WordPress to deliver both a UK and an Ireland (IE) version of a site. Basically if the cookie is set to IE then it will append '_ie' to the meta key for a page which will show the Ireland content where applicable. Here's the site:

```
http://198.211.123.245/fridge-rentals/
```

So switching the countries using the flag in the top right hand corner should change the cookie. The problem is I'm getting multiple cookies of the same name, which means that sometimes it's getting the incorrect value as per the screenshot below (in Chrome):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w61mnba1xfua513/Screenshot%202013-12-31%2014.51.44.png

I'm using the below code to change the cookie:

```
function fr_change_region() {

    if (isset($_GET['change_region'])) {

        $region = sanitize_text_field($_GET['change_region']);
        setcookie('region', $region, time() + 3600, '/');

    }

}

add_action('init', 'fr_change_region' );
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction of what I might be doing wrong? Let me know if you need any further details.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cookies, it works for me. You set the cookie for wrong path (value: IE), maybe it was when you are developing. Browser will rewrite the cookie only if everything is the same (domain, path).

Try to have a look how the cookies are working. By the way, this approach is not good because of the SEO, you have two different contents for same URL.

Comment: It works when you first switch to IE, but not when you switch back to UK again, because the IE cookie is still there - are you able to switch back and forth with no problem?

Comment: Yes, it works. Google Chrome 31. I switched back and forth. Changed page, do the switching. Clear your cookies and try it again. I don't have any cookie for the session. Try to logout and do the switching with clean cookies, then login and do the same.